# Add average to end of mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this :

name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

it displays as a table in php

How would i work out the average for each entry in the table across each row and add it to the end of that table?

This is the code that displays the table :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","education");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM students ((english+math+science)/3) as average");

echo "<table class=\"table1\" border=\"1\">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>English</th>
<th>Maths</th>
<th>Science</th>
<th>Average</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['english'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['math'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['science'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['average'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: add the numbers in the row, then divide by 5: perhaps if you showed how you're making your table we could give you a better answer

Comment: I have this : SELECT name, 1, 2, 3,4,5 sum(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ) as total, sum(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 )/5 as avg from student group by name.

Comment: How would i make that display as an extra column?

Comment: @user3396245 don't use SUM, just remove sum from your query it corect

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT name, one, two, three, four, five, ((one+two+three+four+five)/5) as average
FROM table
```

Comment: Okay , but i want to display the average as an extra column ?

Comment: the query will return 7 columns with the last one called average.  It known as a derived column

Comment: It dosent work . I have added the code that displays the table.

Comment: You can't use a wildcard in your select when creating a derived column.  You have list each column:


SELECT firstname, lastname, english, math, science, ((english+math+science)/3) as average FROM students

Comment: final question , is there any way to limit the average to 2 decimal places

Comment: You will have to switch from using ECHO to printf.  

ie: printf ("%01.2f", $average);

Comment: I need a variable for that . would it be $average = $row['average']; And I place the printf..... inplace of echo "<td>" . $row['average'] . "</td>";

Comment: I would try printf("%01.2f",$row['average']).  If that doesn't work, look at extract to convert your row array into variables.  http://ua.php.net/extract

Comment: I kind of works . It prints all the averages in a line above the table